# How do I set a range across columns rather than down rows?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a formula to use in a larger macro.

I want to drag the EOMONTH formula across a row from the first date to the last filled column.

```vb
Sub DragFormula()
    'Declare variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim formulaRange As Range

    'Set the worksheet to use
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Find the last filled cell in row 1
    lastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Set range to apply the formula to
    Set formulaRange = ws.Range("B1:B" & lastCol)

    'Enter the formula
    formulaRange.Formula = "=EOMONTH(A1,1)"
End Sub
```

The formula is copied down column B instead of across. I know I need to change the notation in this line `Set formulaRange = ws.Range("B1:B" & lastCol)`.

When I modify the line to `Set formulaRange = ws.Range("B1:" & lastCol)` I get:

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

How do I set a range across columns rather than down rows?

Comment: What is the value of `lastCol` when it blows up, and why are you using a column instead of a row?

Comment: `ws.Range("B1:B" &` wants to be followed by a row number greater than 0.

Comment: Maybe `ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,2),ws.Cells(1,lastCol))`

Comment: [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) (free, open-source VBE add-in project of mine) won't write anything for you, but its inspections can help avoiding a number of common issues and sources of bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're trying to do?

THIS:
[image]
TO THIS:
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub DragFormula()

    'Declare variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim formulaRange As Range

    'Set the worksheet to use
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Find the last filled cell in row 1
    lastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1

    'Set range to apply the formula to
    Set formulaRange = ws.Range("B1").Resize(1, lastCol)

    'Enter the formula
    formulaRange.Formula = "=EOMONTH(A1,1)"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: If you need columns, it's easy to flip that on it's side.

Comment: There is no need for `.FillRight`. you can simply use `FormulaRange.Formula = "=EOMONTH(A1,1)"`. Also, it looks like OP wants the formulas in `B1:BLastCol` which would require something like `Set formulaRange = ws.Range("B1").Resize(1, lastCol - 1)` according to John Coleman's 'friendlier' suggestion in OP's comments.

Comment: Ah, didn't reload comments before suggesting. I'm glad he's all set

Comment: That doesn't matter. You can easily fix your code and it may become useful for someone else who might stumble upon it.

Comment: Good Call Will Do.